# linq to xml get all child nodes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to query a `web.Config` file that contains WCF entries.

In the `<service>` node there is a `name attribute` that I am trying to match off of.  So far my code has worked when doing the matching, but my issue is that it only returns 1 of the `<endpoint>` nodes.

For example I could have this snippet of xml:

```
<service name="a">
<endpoint>1</endpoint>
<endpoint>2</endpoint>
<endpoint>3</endpoint>
</service>
<service name="b">
<endpoint>1</endpoint>
<endpoint>2</endpoint>
</service>
```

Everytime I get a match I want it to display all the `<endpoint>` child nodes for that match.

This is the code I have so far:

```
        IEnumerable<XElement> xmlURL =
            from el in xmlFile.Root.Descendants("service")
            where (string)el.Attribute("name") == serviceString
            select el.Element("endpoint");

        Console.WriteLine("Start: " + serviceString);
        foreach (XElement el in xmlURL)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End: " + serviceString + "\n\n");
```

Currently when it does the match only 1 endpoint is shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
    IEnumerable<XElement> xmlURL =
        from el in xmlFile.Root.Descendants("service")
        where (string)el.Attribute("name") == serviceString
        select el.Descendants("endpoint");

    Console.WriteLine("Start: " + serviceString);
    foreach (XElement el in xmlURL)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(el);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("End: " + serviceString + "\n\n");
```

Notice I'm selecting `el.Descendants()` rather than `Element()` which will only ever return the first match (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx).

** **UPDATE** **

I think this is what you want, because you're only conerned with **one** specific match.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> xmlURL = 
    (from el in doc.Root.Descendants("service")
    where el.Attribute("name").Value == serviceString
    select el).First().Descendants();
```

So the result of the LINQ query is, as the compiler tells you, an IEnumerable of IEnumerables, so I take the `First()` result of which gives me now an `IEnumerable<XElement>`, and then we call `Descendants()` on that, which gives you an IEnumerable of the endpoint `XElement`'s.

Also note here that I used the `Value` property of the `XAttribute`, you can't simply cast the `XAttribute` to a string, you have to use that `Value` property.  I didn't catch that in my initial copy/paste answer.

** **UPDATE 2** **

The above query can is probably a little easier to understand like this:

```
doc.Root.Descendants("service")
   .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == serviceString)
   .First()
   .Descendants();
```

** **UPDATE 3** **

There is also the potential for a NRE on the attribute matching, so again this is probably an **even better** verison. =)

```
doc.Root.Descendants("service")
   .Where(x => x.Attribute("name") != null && x.Attribute("name").Value == serviceString)
   .First()
   .Descendants();
```

Comment: In this case when there's only one level of children, Descendants will be fine. Otherwise you may want to use Elements(XName) which only returns the direct children.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I try to use descendants:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @JeffV Right, because what you are wanting (I think) is a single set of results for a single node, but you are potentially selecting the `Descendants()` of many nodes (it's possible that `el.Attribute("name") == serviceString` matches more than 1 element from the compiler's perspective).  So you have to accommodate that somehow.  I'll update my answer with a few suggestions.

Comment: Well that solved 1 problem but now I'm getting an error that states: Sequence contains no elements (I'm assuming when it hits the end).  I am getting multiple endpoints displayed on the screen now.

Comment: Descendants will flatten the hierarchy so I wouldn't use it in the select clause, use el.Children or el.elements.

Comment: @JeffV What line is that exception thrown on?

Comment: I changed that do FirstOrDefault but now I'm getting an Object reference not set ot an instance of an object...  I'm guessing my serviceString doesn't match (which I'm ok with)...

Comment: @ILovePaperTowels - Can you provide an brief example?

Comment: What @ILovePaperTowels means is that if there are children of the endpoint elements, those will get flattened out and returned as well.  So if you have "<endpoint> <baseEndpoint>1</baseEndpoint> </endpoint>" you would get 2 results from that.  Also see my other updates regarding the NRE.

Comment: if serviceString is not an empty string you can abbreviate
x => x.Attribute("name") != null && x.Attribute("name").Value == serviceString
to 
x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == serviceString
The string operator takes care of nulls by returning empty string.